# How to serialize to json on C# application project (no Asp.net)?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2010, serialization, c#-4.0

I wrote an application project in c#.
Is there a way to serialize a collection to Json string format?
If I use C#4? C#3?

Another q: within Visual Studio 2010 ultimate I remember I could search and download dll from the web: Web Downlaoder or so. I cnnot find it again. Does any one know it?

TIA

Comment: If you have two questions, please ask two questions.

Comment: I think the searching and downloading is handled by Nuget (http://nuget.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Nuget http://nuget.org/ using visual studio extension manager, look for json.net in nuget (right click on your project and select Manage nuget packages), add it to your project, you can serialize using this library without adding dependency on system.web

Answer (score 3):

[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) is one way to go:

```
MyType[] collection = ...
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(collection);
```

Comment: I cannot reference Sytem.Web.Scripts from a non web-site poject.

Comment: @EladBenda, you need to reference the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly. If you are targeting the .NET 4.0 Client Profile you will need to switch to .NET 4.0 if you want to use this class. It can be done in desktop application but a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` is required.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) for the Json serialising/deserialising

For downloading the .dlls you probably saw [nuget](http://nuget.org). Once it's installed you can right click on the references folder in the solution explorer and select manage packages.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to Use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Create a new [`JsonResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx)

Or take a look at [Json Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx)